How to get a list of slow mobile web pages without testing page by page?
Our website passes the desktop pagespeed insight test but the mobile version always fails it. We saw the detailed report of LCP failures. But how can we find out which were those slow pages dragging the speed down so that we can work on those pages specifically? Thanks!
Core Website Vitals for Mobile Drill-down Report
We already compressed and zipped all the JS files and reduced CSS file. We tested many pages one by one but could not figure out the slowest pages.
